# How do I get rid of this mould?

Tags: cleaning, mold

Can anyone tell me how I can get rid of this black mould?

It has appeared in the corner of our window ledge, as well as all around the bathroom ceiling.

There is no texture to it, it seems very flat on the surface.

[image]

Comment: Does no-one have any tips? It's black mold on painted brickwork. It does not wipe off with household cleaners or any amount of elbow grease.

Answer (score 5):

You can probably just wipe it off with a bathroom cleaner or some diluted bleach. You should also determine the cause of it, otherwise it will just return. Often in bathrooms it is from a lack of ventilation.